# Is there a way to send Websocket messages through browser console? (SECURITY question)

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

First of all, I am quite new to Websockets(Socket.io) therefore I have a security-type question.

Is it there a way that someone can send a message towards my Websocket server through browser developer console ?

To me, this question matters a lot for the security of my website. If a client can write JavaScript code in his browser console, and send a successful websocket message, I shall change a lot of my current code that I have already done.

In AJAX, you can make XMLHttpRequest object and send it without any problem if you know where the url should be pointed at.
Example :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = 'url_of_.php_file',
        data = 'somedata=123';
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            console.log("The request and response was successful!");
       }
    };

    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.send(data);
```

If a client does something like this to on my website, will he be able to send message through my websocket without my permission?(If my idea is wrong, please write legit code for doing so)

```
.......socket implementation.........

    mywebsocket.emit('send_money','230.000');
```

Comment: The user can do anything he wants on the client side.

Comment: The problem is if he is somehow able to find out my websocket variable name. Don't know how he could get it if my JS code is obfuscated.

Comment: Obfuscating doesn't help, at all. The network tab shows you exactly where in you JS file the WS connection was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to send Websocket messages through browser console?

Absolutely. You can use the developer tools in almost any web browser to find the socket object and call its functions or modify it from the console. And this goes for *any* javascript object that exists locally in the client's browser.

Obfuscation can only be used to deter a less determined user from tampering with your client. It doesn't actually prevent the user from accessing those functions and variables.

> If a client does something like this to on my website, will he be able to send message through my websocket without my permission?

Simply opening a websocket to the client is implicitly giving permission for the client to send *anything* to your server. So,

**Never trust the client.**

If you are allowing the client to determine anything of importance locally, you should assume that a savvy opponent will abuse or circumvent that client-side decision. Such as in your example, they could send more money than they actually have, or maybe even negative money!

Your server needs to be capable of handling *any* data that comes in on that connection, from incoherent garbage to attempted exploits. So always validate that messages sent from the clients are legal using server-side logic. This is the only place where it makes sense to implement your rules or permissions, since *everything* in the client code is open to tampering.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, I just got one more question.
How could a client find out my socket variable name? All the client sees is something like this : https://prnt.sc/qam7ts

Comment: @Karizon, By looking at the javascript files the browser loads from your site. Even if they're obfuscated the variables are still there right in the file, and if you didn't ofuscate the dependencies like socket.io then it makes it quite easy to find. Also, you can't be certain which browsers, debuggers, or developer tools the user will have at their disposal to reverse engineer your client's code.